# How to print random array in array_slice($some_content, 0, 2, true)?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose:

```
$some_content = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu");
```

Now I used:

```
$slice = array_slice($some_content, 0, 2, true);
```

To choose only first two values "abc" and "def".

My question is I want a code that display "abc"(this is fixed) but randomly choose any other value of array like "ghi" or "jkl" or "pqr" etc. How to do this?

Comment: Use [array_rand](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_rand.asp) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$some_content = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu");
$fixedEl = array_shift($some_content);
$randomEl = array_rand($some_content);
```

Comment: array_shift returns the value, array_rand returns the key, do `$randomEl = $some_content[array_rand($some_content)];` instead

Comment: No its not working your code return two values of array but the element at position is not fixed it keeps changing after refresh. the abc must be fixed. This is the requirement

Comment: `array_shift` always removes and returns the first value from the passed array, so then I'm thinking that your array changes?

Answer (score 0):

Use this trick :

```
$source = array("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu");
$pick = [$source[0], $source[array_rand(array_slice($source, 1, null, true))]];
print_r($pick);
```

Comment: you are welcome, then up-vote and accept my answer as solution ;-)